# Write a program that converts the variable num to string. var num = 35.36 ; Remove the dot to display “3536” display in your browser.how to do this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to do this in javascript I have been on this so please help me out

Comment: please show us your attempt first

Comment: please show us your code what have you attempted so far

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the number to a string. Then replace the dot with nothing.

```
const num = 35.36;
const without = num.toString().replace(".", "");
```